# Chome iframes location undefined no longer working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

Chrome v. 35.0.1916.114 m seems to have changed the way that it handles or implements `iframe` in the DOM.  This has had the effect that some previously working code has become broken.  For example:

```
frames['SomeFrame'].location.href = "SomePage.html";
```

No longer works because `location` is undefined.  How should this be handled moving forward?  It's likely that this old code improperly used the DOM, and until now Chrome had supported it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace that with `frames['SomeFrame'].src`

Comment: If you change the value of `.src`, it adds an entry to the history. So, this doesn't provide an equivalent of `.location.replace()`.